# Tableau Unable to create Stacked Area Chart

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to create Stacked Area Chart in Tableau.

Workbook is on [Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/Finance_151/Inflation-AdjustedTrend)

Data is left joined via CUSIP, i.e
- excel sheet of CUSIP with interest rates
- excel sheet of CUSIP with date and index ratios

Workbook is filtered by CUSIP, and has a parameter called `Principal` (integer) which the user can input via adjusting slider, and has calculated field `Inflation-Adjusted Principal` which is

```
[Principal] * [Index Ratio]
```

Now, I am trying to create [this type of Area Map](https://www.interworks.com/sites/default/files/TECTAreaChart1.jpg) from [this webpage](https://www.interworks.com/blog/ccapitula/2014/11/13/tableau-essentials-chart-types-area-charts-continuous-discrete)

But my chart ends up like this (refer tab `Inflation-Adjusted Trend`). It just adds up everything together.

[image]

And if I try to deliberately create an Area Chart, it looks like a bunch of color blocks (refer tab `Inflation-Adjusted Trend 2`) ... How to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a quick check on the range of your `[Index Ratio]`s:

```
MAX([Index Ratio]) - MIN([Index Ratio])
```

For every CUSIP, it's `0.00007`.

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| Cusip     | Max. Index Ratio | Min. Index Ratio |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| 912828H45 | 1.00760          | 1.00753          |
| 912828TE0 | 1.03779          | 1.03772          |
| 912828SA9 | 1.05443          | 1.05436          |
| 912828QV5 | 1.05888          | 1.05881          |
| 912828PP9 | 1.09097          | 1.09090          |
| 912828NM8 | 1.09431          | 1.09424          |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

For any line, if your scale is too large, it's going to look like a straight line. Here's a line chart of a single CUSIP's `[Inflation-Adjusted Principal]`:

[image]

Here's that same line chart if I change the axis to not show zero:

[image]

The axis now spans from approximately the min to the max, so we can see the detail easily.

All of your `[Index Ratio]`s are pretty far apart from one another, considering the scale. Here's a shot of another line chart, but this time with a line per CUSIP:

[image]

If you're going to group by `[CUSIP]`, your scale is going to be too large to see the detail in the lines in this type of view. This isn't a Tableau problem, it's just the nature of your data. Looks like you're going to need to find another creative way to visualize this, or choose a different aspect of the data to visualize that can tell the same story.

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with the data some more!